# Is it possible to give an object to a ListView, but to display a string?

Tags: java, string, listview, singleton

Is it possible to show a String (like testObject.getName() ) in a ListView but work with an object (public class ListView   -> so T is an object not a String). I am trying this because i want to show names of Objects in a List and if i click on one, it should open more Details about the Object in an other Window. I handle that with a singleton Class but at the moment it is only possible that in the ListView the reference number and not the name is displayed.

```
public class TestController implements Initalizable{

    @FXML
    private ListView<Test_Object> lvTest;

    private ObservableList <Test_Object> obsList;
    private Test_Object to1 = new Test_Object();
    private Test_Object to2 = new Test_Object();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
         TestSingleton.setTestController(this);

         to1.setLab_name("testName1");
         to2.setLab_name("testName2");

         obsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fl1, fl2);
         lvTest.setItems(obsList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a hundred percent sure what you are trying to achieve and/or what your output is. From what I've figured out is that you probably simply want to override the toString() method inside your class so it returns a more sensible String than what Java returns by default.